# Meaning of "show up on the scale" in context

Tags: sentence-meaning

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/DsVzKCk066g). It is at around 2 minute and 7 second.

> So, exercise is the single best thing you can do for yourself, but if you think it is going to **show up on the scale**, think again.

I am aware of what the phrasal verb *show up* means, I cannot get what the speaker means by that whole piece.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but I wanted to emphasize that "the phrasal verb 'show up'" has [multiple meanings](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/show%20up). It can mean "appear"/"arrive" (as in this example), but also "to cause to look bad by comparison".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Loosely translated, it means that while exercise is good for you, it won’t necessarily make you lose (or gain) weight.

The scale in this context is the kind you use to weigh yourself, and if something shows up on the scale, it means that the scale measures a difference, in either direction.